# Automatically play a video on my site at a certain time of day

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Context: A video on an html page.

I have a hidden video on an html page.

I'd like the video to appear (and autoplay) daily at 12:00 noon EST.

Can this be accomplished with JavaScript? Where should I start?

Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have a DOM element as a placeholder (either a image or the paused video) by using the date object in a loop you can then fire the HTML5 video by

```
document.getElementById('video_id').play();
```

so something like

```
function checkTimeAndPlay() {
    var date = new Date();
    if (date.getHours() == 12 && date.getMinutes() == 0) {
        document.getElementById('video_id').play();
    } else {
        setTimeout("checkTimeAndPlay", 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works - but is there any way to trigger it without a page refresh? The video will show if I refresh the page at the set time but not if I'm on the page before the set time.

Answer (score 2):

```
var targetHours = 12;
var targetMinutes = 0;
var date = new Date();
var hours = date.getHours();
var minutes = date.getMinutes();
var minutesLeft = (60*24 + (targetHours - hours)*60 + targetMinutes - minutes) % (60*24);
setInterval(function () {alert("Hello")}, minutesLeft * (60*1000))
```

This doesn't need to check every second like the solution of @Burrito. If you want it to trigger every 24hours (if someone leaves the page open for so long), set the timer again in the called function with a 24h timeout.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise you to look into the JavaScript `Date` object which gives you access to the current time and a whole lot more.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date